# CSS selectors without knowing the type of element it is

Tags: svg.js

I'm trying to render game boards. I define a generic "piece" group, which could contain many different elements. There's nothing stopping the user from making a game piece as complex as they want. But what I *do* need to know is which elements need to be filled with the current player colour. I was hoping to do that using `select()` and CSS selectors.

The problem, though, is that the SVG.js appears to prepend the class name with the type of element, but the rendering code shouldn't need to have that information.

Here's the code:

```js
var canvas = SVG('canvas')

// Create a new group in the <defs> tag that will contain the piece
const group = canvas.defs().group().id("piece");

// Add various elements to the piece.
group.circle(100)
  // Only *this* element should be filled with a colour
  .addClass("playerfill")
  .fill("#fff")
  .stroke({width: 2, color: "#000"});
group.circle(5).center(50,50).fill("black");

var use = SVG.get("piece");
// I have to prepend `circle.` to make this work!
var set = use.select("circle.playerfill").fill("red");
canvas.use(use);
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Perlkonig/so12hev3/.

If not by ID (the group might contain multiple elements that need filling) or by CSS class (I apparently need to know the type of element the user selected), how can I tag elements in a group for later selection and manipulation?

UPDATED:

Here's the answer. Thanks, Duncan!

https://jsfiddle.net/Perlkonig/8b92xdj1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add any attribute you like as long as it starts with `data-`, so for example `data-condition="alive"`. You can then select with the CSS selector `[data-condition="alive"]`.

You can do more complex selection with attributes, see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp